# Find the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th occurrences of the specific column header in the worksheet vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying find the specific column header occurrences in worksheet. for example
header name `payout date`, need to find the occurrences of `payout date` in worksheet like 1st occurrence cell address, 2nd Occurrence cell address, 3rd occurrence cell address and 4th occurrence cell address  . Any suggestion it would be appreciated. the below code not working correctly

```
Sub find()
d = "Payout Date"
Set r = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.find(d)
Debug.Print r.Address
Set r = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.FindNext(d)
Debug.Print r.Address
Set r = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.FindNext(d)
Debug.Print r.Address
Set r = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.FindNext(d)
Debug.Print r.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the headers all in a specific column or row?

Comment: so what is your actual output and what did you expect? And what is your question, you didn't ask one? Did you have a look at the example of the documentation how [Range.FindNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-findnext-method-excel) works correctly? There is a full example how to implement it.

Comment: @L.Dutch its one specific column

Comment: @Peh based on the input like if we give 1 need to find 1st column header and get the value from that column, if we give 2 need to find 2nd column header and get the value from that column etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following might be helpful.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, cnt As Long
    Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim cellFound As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  'change Sheet1 to your data sheet
    Set rng = ws.Range("1:1") 'assuming headers are in row 1 else change 1 to row number with headers
    Set rng2 = rng(1, Columns.Count)
    cnt = 3              'number of occurrences to find
    i = 1
    With rng
    Set cellFound = .find(what:="ID", After:=rng2, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not cellFound Is Nothing Then
           firstAddress = cellFound.Address
           Do
               Debug.Print "Occurrence " & i & " : " & cellFound.Address
               i = i + 1
               If i > cnt Then: Exit Do
               Set cellFound = .FindNext(cellFound)
           Loop While cellFound.Address <> firstAddress
         End If
      End With
End Sub
```

See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: I was trying to get something similar, from row A1 to last cell. However, i was getting the second find to the fifth. And not the first to forth. Similar to yours, just changing this part `Loop While Not cF Is Nothing And cF.Address <> FirstAddress And i<=cnt` and `cnt=4`.

Comment: Using your formula i still got `Occurrence 1 : $A$2
Occurrence 2 : $A$3
Occurrence 3 : $A$4
Occurrence 4 : $A$5`  with `Set rng = ws.Columns(1)` And just don't work if the first occurrence is the first cell of the range

Comment: @danieltakeshi - Let me check.

Comment: @danieltakeshi - Yup, there was some issue, I've updated the code.

Comment: I normally use this function and didn't know how to fix this part, because i never had this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`FindNext` method has optional argument of `Range` type, ommit it or make it:

```
Set r = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.FindNext(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably something that I am doing a few times per day. Thus, I have built my custom function for it, which I can easily share. If you have ideas for improvement - I am willing to hear them.

This is the function:

```
Public Function fnLngLocateValueCol(ByVal strTarget As String,               
                   ByRef wksTarget As Worksheet, _
                   Optional lngRow As Long = 1, _
                   Optional lngMoreValuesFound As Long = 1, _
                   Optional blnLookForPart = False, _
                   Optional blnLookUpToBottom = True) As Long  

    Dim lngValuesFound          As Long
    Dim rngLocal                As Range
    Dim rngMyCell               As Range

    fnLngLocateValueCol = -999
    lngValuesFound = lngMoreValuesFound

    With wksTarget
        Set rngLocal = .Range(.Cells(lngRow, 1), .Cells(lngRow, Columns.Count))
    End With        

    For Each rngMyCell In rngLocal
        If blnLookForPart Then
            If strTarget = Left(rngMyCell, Len(strTarget)) Then
                If lngValuesFound = 1 Then
                    fnLngLocateValueCol = rngMyCell.Column
                    If blnLookUpToBottom Then Exit Function
                Else
                    Call Decrement(lngValuesFound)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            If strTarget = Trim(rngMyCell) Then
                If lngValuesFound = 1 Then
                    fnLngLocateValueCol = rngMyCell.Column
                    If blnLookUpToBottom Then Exit Function
                Else
                    Call Decrement(lngValuesFound)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next rngMyCell    

End Function
```

Thus, if you want to get the first value of row 1 in the active sheet, you call like this:

```
fnLngLocateValueCol("valueToSearchFor",ActiveSheet)
```

For the second value, you call like this:

```
?fnLngLocateValueCol("valueToSearchFor",ActiveSheet,lngMoreValuesFound:=2)
```

For the last value you call like this:

```
?fnLngLocateValueCol("valueToSearchFor",ActiveSheet,blnLookUpToBottom:=false)
```

If you have **ValueToSearchFor** in the columns, you can find it as well by looking for anything that starts with **Value**. Like this:

```
?fnLngLocateValueCol("Value",ActiveSheet,blnLookForPart:=True)
```

The row, on which you are looking for is also an optional parameter (`lngRow`), with value 1.

There are also optional parameters for `lngRow` (when it is not the top row) or `blnLookForPart`, when you are looking for part. **-999** is the code for value not found.

So far it works for more than 6 months in a few VBA applications.

---

The routine `Decrement` which is referred in the code is the following:

```
Public Sub Decrement(ByRef value_to_decrement As Variant, Optional l_minus As Double = 1)
    value_to_decrement = value_to_decrement - l_minus
End Sub
```